# Switch Partition To External Table

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible in SQL Server to switch a partition of old relational data out to an external table (Polybase to Azure Blob Storage)? I've not been able to find the answer in my searches

Answer (score 1):

A partition `SWITCH` is a meta-data only operation that does not physically move data. Consequently, you can't use it to move data outside the physical SQL Server database or file/filegroup within the database.